# Prevent user from editing or deleting a validation rule

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I have a validation rule on Account object that prevent users, belonging to certain profiles, to edit a field. There is no issue with validation rule.

Problem is, when I login as the user who is prevented from editing a field, I can access validation rule and can edit/delete it.

I searched in Profile/Permission set for any such checkbox which prevent users from accessing validation rules but I found nothing.

How do I prevent user from editing/deleting a validation rule?!

Comment: So is everyone admin profile? You should only have one or two...

Comment: No, not everyone is admin profile. They are on custom profiles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These permissions required for creating and editing validation rules:

**To view field validation rules:** View Setup and Configuration

**To define or change field validation rules:** Customize Application

You can find these permissions under **system permission of profile or Permission set.**

Basically if you have standard profile then you can't remove them also **removing these permission you will lost a lot of other setup access too** so keep that in mind.

Comment: Can you write out those permissions in your post? Not super mobile friendly as is. Also these permissions *can* be assigned via `Permission Set`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson There you go :) We can provide these permissions but can not revoke if profile is standard.That makes question really important.

Comment: Are these included in the Standard User Profile? Or do you mean the standard admin profile?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Actually my concern is the permissions which we want to remove.They are actually pretty big setup related permissions and if we remove them the user will lost access to lot of other setup related access too, like editing custom setting etc.So if it is even a custom profile in that case also it is a big issue.

Comment: I agree it's a big change. I can't say I would sympathize much with those users though. Too many cooks in the kitchen are bound to burn things eventually.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yupe i guess you are right.Actually i always think there should be a proper thought process before providing users there permissions like who is going to access what.Basically a lower set of permissions from profile and then increase them through permission set.

Comment: Permission sets are definitely more flexible.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Frodo. That did the trick! He is a basic user so I don't mind him not having setup features.